# Testing integration between two systems

Tags: testing, integration, integration-testing

I have two systems:

1. REST web application which return data in xml
2. Windows service which daily gets data from 1st web app and sync it wit its database.

Question: how to make integration testing for this applications (check whether data is sunchronised corectly)? Is it possible to automate such testing?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would send a request from `2` and validate my database data at `2`.  This forms a whole journey (E2E) there by interacting with as many other systems involved.  You may also need to consider different scenarios/paths so that as much interaction is covered.

Comment: Do you mean "request from 1"? So do I need some "input info" and "expected result"? Wha if I don't own 1 app?

Comment: Yes you need an input and expected result. You don't have to own `1`. Treat `1` like a black box where you send a request and receive a response that will be validated by you.